# Using Excel to serach for all values in a column, or range, and then copying that row to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

Does anyone know how to search for data that is in one sheet against data in another sheet in Excel? The data is in a column on each of the 2 sheets. Both are Serial Numbers located in Column D Row 2 and down.

Comment: `vlookup`? `index/match`?

Comment: I was looking into these and xlookup but I'm unsure how to get it to where it only copies serial numbers that are not found. Can you assist?

Comment: vlookup will give you those that are found so the rest would be not found.

Comment: Doesn't vlookup only do left and right of the cell and not up and down?

Comment: I guess using your words, it does right and up and down. Sounds like you want index/match.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` sounds just like what you’re after.

```
=INDEX(D2:D12, MATCH(“ValueToFind”, E2:E12,0),2)
```

Where D2:D12 are the range where you’d like to retrieve values from, and E2:E12 are the range where “ValueToFind” are located. Replace with a range to make it dynamic.